# Expresion regular para un serial

Tags: regex

Me gustaría una expresión regular para validar un input, donde solo se aceptan números, letras y guiones, por ejemplo:

```
58D8E-5662D-467BF-BFF44-08228
```

Lo único que tengo es esta expresión donde solo me valida letra y números

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

Solo necesito agregar el guion `-`.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la siguiente expresión regular validas que el campo ingresado contenga al menos una letra, un número y un guion:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

Puedes verlo como funciona en el siguiente código:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$" value="58D8E-5662D-467BF-BFF44-08228" required> <!-- serial correcto -->
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$" value="58D8E5662D467BFBFF4408228" required> <!-- serial sin guiones -->
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$" value="1234567891011121314" required> <!-- serial con solo números -->
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$" value="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS" required> <!-- serial con solo letras -->
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Ojo que OP no aclaró en qué lenguaje está trabajando ;)

Comment: Sí, de alguna otra forma, quería mostrar cómo es que funciona esta expresión regular. Aunque el OP menciona *"para validar un input"* -> me hace entender que está trabajando con formularios.